# Sed/Awk in bash script

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have some data which is in the following format:

```
bruce   434355/512000 (84.8349609375%)
oliver   217542/512000 (42.488671875%)
kareem   236778/563200 (42.0415482954545%)
```

The data in the second column is in KB and I want to extract the first part (before the /) and display that only, like so:

```
 bruce    424.17MB (84.8349609375%)
 oliver   212.44MB (42.488671875%)
 kareem   231.24MB (42.0415482954545%)
```

Is there a way in sed or awk to do that?

Alternately, what I have done is extract the second column using awk, wrote it into another file and the display one line from each file within a while loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '$2=$2/1024"MB"' file
```

And if you only want to keep two decimals, do this:

```
awk '{printf "%s %.2fMB %s\n", $1, $2/1024, $3 }' file
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following awk script:

```
function human(x) {
    s="kMGTEPYZ";
    while (x>=1000 && length(s)>1)
        {x/=1024; s=substr(s,2)}
    return int(x+0.5) substr(s,1,1)
}
{
    split($2, a, "/");
    $2 = human(a[1]);
    print
}
```

save it to a file and execute it this way:

```
awk -f awk.script your.txt
```

The output is:

```
bruce 424M (84.8349609375%)
oliver 212M (42.488671875%)
kareem 231M (42.0415482954545%)
```

The `human` function is taken from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44087. Thanks!